# Qual a diferença entre @Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.css") e só "/css/bootstrap.css"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-3, razor

Estou a aprender a programar uma aplicação baseada em MVC4 e Bootstrap. Logo no inicio do projeto deparei-me com um quebra cabeças:

No **_Layout.cshtml** eu eu tinha `<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`, o Bootstrap funcionava bem numa *view* (`Home/BootSchool`) e na outra não formatava o HTML (`Student/AllStudents`). Depois de umas pesquisas resolvi o meu problema usando `<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet">`.

Terá algo a ver com o redirecionamento? No código fonte da página, o link é igual no dois modos e ao clicar nele sou redirecionado corretamente para o CSS do Bootstrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Não é igual a isto, por mais que pareça:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet">
```

No primeiro modo, o caminho do arquivo será relativo. Ou seja:

```
/Student/AllStudents/css/bootstrap.css
```

No segundo modo, você está dizendo claramente que o fonte CSS deve ser procurado começando pela raiz, porque pediu para o [`UrlHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx) resolver isto pra você (usando o til, que indica o caminho raiz da rota). Ou seja:

```
/css/bootstrap.css
```

É considerada má prática referenciar um arquivo sem passar pelo `UrlHelper` justamente porque esse problema de rota relativa pode ocorrer.

Comment: pensei que seria jsutamente essa a diferença, porém estranhei quando era redirecionado corretamente nos dois casos para o ficheiro correto. No código fonte tinha exatamente o mesmo link para os dois casos(/css/bootstrap.css).

Comment: É bastante normal colocar a referência fixa, mas não é uma boa prática porque abre espaço pra problemas.

Answer (score 3):

Eles mudaram isso na versao 4. Voce tambem pode usar direto `~/css/file.css`.

Comment: Só para deixar uma fonte [New in ASP.NET MVC4: Razor changes](http://beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-razor-changes.html). Isso significa que `<link href="~/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">` deve funcionar no MVC4 correto?

Comment: Eu sempre uso direto ~/css/bootstrap.css e nunca tive problema. Valeu por referenciar um artigo. Estava ontem do celular é meio complicado. Abs.